# Constraints on argument to sympy.Symbol

Tags: sympy

I am looking for an official *specification* of the constraints on sympy's **Symbol()** function.

The use itself is not subject of this question

> x = sympy.Symbol("whatever")
> associates the python variable **x** with the symbol **whatever**

I can however not find a specification of what qualifies as an argument to sympy.Symbol; out of curiosity and for later use in MathJax I entered

> sympy.Symbol("\textcolor{red}{whatever}")
> In IDLE, which caused the program to hang, therefore my

**Question:**
in which freely online accessible documents are the constraints on sympy.Symbol formally defined.

searching online for quite a while I could only find examples, but no definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are somewhat light on detail:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.symbol

I think that any string should be valid though. I'm not sure about the problem you had with IDLE. In isympy that works fine:

```
In [5]: Symbol("\\textcolor{red}{whatever}")                                                                                                                                      
Out[5]: \textcolor{red}{whatever}
```